Cryptic simulated voltage in Circuit Lab
Simulating in Circuit Lab (on SE.EE), I discovered some behaviour where the addition of an open-circuit switch changes a voltage (by over five volts).  See below: the D1.A-D2.K junction should surely be at the same voltage as the D3.A-D4.K junction?
What explanation is there for what's being simulated?
(For what little it's worth, my real circuit measures 42mV, which is also cryptic to me, but I'm prepared to believe this is a Heisenberger from the input impedance the meter -- a Fluke 115, listed as >10MΩ -- capacitance from breadboard etc.)
Screengrabs of hovering on the circuit shown below:


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Why do you say "changes a voltage (by almost half a volt)" <-- where is that indicated?

Thanks @Andyaka, my mistake, corrected: "by over five volts."

Just an observation. There is a voltage on the open side of the switch also. The model may have some leakage resistance built in.

@MathKeepsMeBusy well spotted! Turns out this is exactly right 10^15 ohm across the switch and one side 10^15 to ground.

Simulated circuit
It appears Circuit Lab switches have a 999 TΩ hidden resistance to GND node.
This might be a way to work around simulation problems which would occur with floating nodes.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Another problem with the simulation is the unrealistically low value for 1N4004 reverse leakage current, about 80 pA at 12 V. Actual diodes will leak nano or microamperes in this configuration, and the ratio of the leakages determines the voltage. The simulator has exactly equivalent leakage for all diodes, resulting in the seemingly perfect 6 volt value.
Real circuit
When you build this for real, whatever device you use to measure the voltage will load it much more than the reverse biased diodes do. Your meter will read $$\mathrm{V = R_{meter} \times I_{leakage}}$$
From your 42 mV reading with 10 MΩ voltmeter, we get 4.2 nA. This is a reasonable leakage current. Vishay's datasheet gives this graph:

Because 12 V is just 3% of the rated reverse voltage, we can expect leakage below 20 nA.

Ah now that makes perfect sense.  Further experiments show it's 10^15 ohm; across the switch (not 999e12) and another 10^15 ohm to ground on one side (see my additional answer.)  Can I suggest you edit my diagram into your answer?  (Or I'm happy to do it if you don't object.)

Let's start with reality: -

For what little it's worth, my real circuit measures 42mV, which is
also cryptic to me

That's because the upper and lower diodes are not identical but also because your meter is loading the diode at the bottom. Try measuring the diode at the top and I bet you get a voltage that is not perfectly 6 volts.
I say 6 volts because both diodes are reversed biased and, with an ideal voltage measurement device you'd measure 6 volts with two absolutely identical series diodes across a 12 volt supply.
As for your simulator it's likely the simulator is basing the number it calculates on some very short time frame measurement and the switch's self-capacitance (it might be listed as a parameter) is throwing the measurement off.
In other words you have to be careful with spot measurements produced in a simulator. Your best chance to resolve this is to run a short simulation (of a few milliseconds) and looking at the voltage waveform. Ensure that the simulation is restricted from calculating steady-state values before it begins.

Real circuit: certainly that makes sense.  Measured drop over D1=80mV, over D2=42mV, D1.K-D2,A=12V, which is consistent with diodes being 150x and 200x the input of the meter.  Simulator (I'm sure you meant 6V top and bottom, not 3V: DC source is 12V).  Circuit Sim doesn't have any capacitance for switches; in any case the switch is connected to nothing, so I'm still surprised.  Will try various dynamic sim and see what happens.   Many thanks as always for your insights.

@jonathanjo oops yes about the 6 volts.... fixing....

Even if the diodes were identical, +/-10% they have a small capacitance which increases with diode current rating and the switch model also has a small capacitance which may be modelled in the sim. (but not likely)
Even if D1,D2 were different by 0.1%, as the reverse voltage rises on D1, the C lowers and causes the voltage to rise again until it stabilizes. D2 does the opposite.  Whereas D3, D4 impedance must be identical.

The ratio of these Csw/(2*Cdiode+Csw) will lower the voltage even with low f across 10Meg can and will lower the floating voltage on the mechanical switch side with your meter and maybe the Heisenberger uncertainty is in Circuit Lab's simulation of the diodes.
The diode capacitance is max at 0V and reduces with rising positive Vr or negative Vf
The 1N400x rating is 15 pF @ -4V @ 1MHz.
Source: https://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf

@jpa has the proper answer: this is just a diagram to demonstrate the switch's hidden resistances in Circuit Lab simulations.
Switches in Circuit Lab appear to be modelled with a hidden 1015Ω to ground and a hidden 1015Ω across the contacts, as demonstrated by the following circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

To the downvoter: did you try it?  Please leave a comment with your objection.  Thank you!
